# Call React-Redux dispatch function from non function component while using wrapper

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux, react-redux

I have a React-Redux store which is wrapped in a `next-redux-wrapper`. I want to dispatch a function outside of react component but I am unable to do so because of the wrapper. Is there a way to import `store` and use `dispatch` while using wrapper?

```js
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    [authSlice.name]: authSlice.reducer
});
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const makeConfiguredStore = () => {
   const store = configureStore({
   reducer: rootReducer,
   middleware: [sagaMiddleware],
   devTools: true,
 });
 sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
 return store;
};

export const makeStore = () => {
  const persistConfig = {
    key: 'nextjs',
    whitelist: ['auth'],
    storage,
  };

  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

  const store: any = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: [sagaMiddleware],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  });

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  store.__persistor = persistStore(store); // Nasty hack
  return store;
}

export const wrapper = createWrapper<AppStore>(makeStore);

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type AppState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>;
```

I am trying to use this on a axios helper file, For example:

```js
const setHeaders = async () => {

  const token = await refreshOrAccessToken();

  if(!token){
    // const store = makeStore();

    store.dispatch(signoutUser(SESSION_EXPIRY_MSG))
    msalInstance.logoutRedirect();
    throw Error(SESSION_EXPIRY_MSG)
  }
  axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
};
```

Comment: You may be able to create a store object first, then create a function that returns it instead of creating a store. Can you [edit] to include an example [mcve] where you are wanting/trying to access the store outside the expected areas?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I have edited the code snipped including a place where I need to access the store.

Comment: From the above snippet, I am able to dispatch signoutUser function but, its just for the name sake, Its not doing any activities at all, not updating data to local storage or doing anything at all. Whereas if I call the same from a react component, It is updating the persist store data

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to create the store normally and rework the `makeStore` function to simply return the store.

Example:

```js
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({ ...multiple_reducers_here });
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'nextjs',
  whitelist: ['auth'],
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store: any = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaulrMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware),
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export const makeStore = () => store;

export const wrapper = createWrapper<AppStore>(makeStore);

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type AppState = ReturnType<store.getState>;
```

You should now be able to import the exported `store` in your code and call `store.dispatch` to dispatch actions to the same store instance that is provided to your app code.

Comment: Using this, I am getting following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Comment: @AnkitShah Can you edit the post to share that complete error message and accompanying stacktrace? Can you also clarify if this is occurring server-side or client-side?